# Variable file size reported while downloading file from Http Server

Tags: java, download

I am trying to make a http client application which downloads file from http server.
I am having the following issue.

Whenever I try to download and store the file, the content of the file gets truncated.
Also each time I try to download and store the file, the size of the stored file differs. I am unable to find the reason for the same.

Sample url

http://example.com/filename.fileextension

Following are the code snippets which I have tried.

```
    URL url = new URL(uri.toURL().toString());
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "binary/data");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();

    File destination = new File("D:/videos1");
    destination.mkdirs();
    File targetFile = new File(destination.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"test.xyz");
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
```

Approach 1: Using Apache IO Utils

```
    IOUtils.copy(ins, outStream);
```

Approach 2: Using buffer

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = ins.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

Approach 3: Using Files.copy

```
    Files.copy(ins, targetFile.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

End of Code

```
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(ins);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);
```

Comment: Except that you forgot to close the outStream - or may be you only forgot to post it - your code should work. Maybe the error is between the snippets.

Comment: Have closed both InputStream and OutputStream in     IOUtils.closeQuietly(ins);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);"

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't see that. Blinders :). I tested your code, all 3 approaches. It works fine. I tested it with downloading a 3MB zip file from a local web application and in all 3 cases, the copy was binary equal to the original. It seems, that the problem is not inside the code you posted. Maybe the file is too large or something else. Have you testet with small files and files on other servers ?